# Hadoop configuring multi node cluster on two machines with different names

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop

I followed the tutorial on 
[michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/](http://michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/)

to setup my multi node hadoop cluster.
the only difference being that my user name on one machine is hduser and on the other machine it is hndata1, now when i start the dfs on master it asks me the password for hduser@host2 but i do not have the hduser account on host2 it is named as hndata1. where do i need to make changes so that it works fine.
Note: the ssh keys are added to both the hduser@host1 and hndata1@host2 machine so both commands

```
ssh hduser@host1
ssh hndata1@host2
```

both work fine and do not require a password

Also, does it affect the hadoop installation if i have open jdk version of java on host1 and sun java on host 2?

Answer (score 0):

- Try adding this line to `hadoop-env.sh` configuration file:

  ```
  export HADOOP_USER_NAME="user"
  ```
- Or create a file named `config` in `~/.ssh/` folder that contains:

  ```
  Host host2
      HostName host2
      User hndata1
  ```